# Lower bound KL distance of non linear transform of a Gaussian with a family of mean zero Gaussian

Tags: kullback-leibler

Let $X \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma_x^2)$ and let $f :\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a smooth nonlinear transformation such that $\mathbb{E}[f(X)]=0$. I am wondering what kind of restrictions one can put on the function $f$ such that I can find a (uniform) lower bound of the KL-distance between the random variable $f(X)$ and any mean zero Gaussian random variable $Y$.

More precisely, I wish to make the statement that for a fixed $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ belonging to some class of functions $\mathcal{C}$, there exists an $\varepsilon > 0$ such that for any mean zero Gaussian random variable $Y$ we have

\begin{equation}
KL(f(X) \Vert Y) \geq \varepsilon.
\end{equation}

We make the further requirement that $\mathbb{E}[f(X)]=0$. I am wondering what are some sufficient criteria for the KL distance to be uniformly bounded below. I have read up on Pinskers inequality,
$$
\delta (P,Q) \leq \sqrt{1/2KL(P \Vert Q)}
$$
where
$$
\delta(P,Q) = \sup\{|P(A) - Q(A)| : A \text{ measurable}\}
.$$
This implies a sufficient condition, namely that
$$
P_X(\{x \in \mathbb{R} : f(x) \geq 0\}) \neq 0.5
$$
since we would have
$$
P_{f(X)}((0, \infty)) \neq P_Y((0,\infty))= 0.5
$$
and thus the quantity $0 < |P_{f(X)}((0, \infty))-0.5|\leq \delta(P_{f(X)},P_Y)$ could be used to bound the KL distance uniformly. I am thus looking for the greatest possible class of functions $\mathcal{C}$ such that the statement above holds.

EDIT:
As whuber points out, a better way to ask my question would be to define
$$\mathcal{C} = \{f :\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} | f \text{ measurable }, \text{ there exists } \varepsilon > 0 \text{ st. } KL(P_{f(X)} || \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2)) \geq \varepsilon \text{ for all } \sigma^2 > 0 \}
$$

What I am looking for is then a way of verifying if a specific $f$ belongs to $\mathcal{C}$. For example, if $\mathbb{E}f(X) \neq 0$, then we certainly have $f \in \mathcal{C}$. Or if $P_{X}(\{x \in \mathbb{R} : f(x) \geq 0 \}) \neq 0$ we also have $f \in \mathcal{C}$. I am looking for easily testable such criteria such as those, if those exist.

In particular, I would like to be able to make a statement such as: if $f$ is smooth and non-linear, then $f \in \mathcal{C}$. Because all of the non-linear transformations that preserve Gaussianity that I have seen have been not been continuous.

Comment: The question seems framed a little backwards.  You have already defined your class of functions: they are precisely the set of functions that meet your criteria.  It sounds like you are looking for some alternative characterization of that set, but that's an awfully vague question: what *kinds* of characterizations are you looking for?

Comment: Fair point, I have updated the question text.

Comment: Thank you.  But it's easy to find a sequence of "smooth and nonlinear" functions $f$ for which $\varepsilon$ must shrink to zero.   (Just making $f$ agree with the identity map within any neighborhood of $0$ will cause the KL divergences to converge to zero as $\sigma$ gets small.)  You will need *quantitative,* not *qualitative,* characterizations.

Comment: BTW, intuitively the condition for arbitrarily small $\sigma^2$ means that if $f(x)$ does not closely approximate either $x$ or $-x$ in a neighborhood of the origin there will be a positive $\varepsilon$ for all $\sigma^2$ in any bounded interval; and the condition for arbitrarily large $\sigma^2$ means that if $f$ does not closely approximate the same $x$ or $-x$ in a neighborhood of $\{\pm\infty\},$ then there will be a positive $\varepsilon$ for all sufficiently large $\sigma^2.$ In other words, $\mathcal C$ contains all functions whose germs at $\{0,\pm\infty\}$ differ from $x$ or $-x.$

Comment: Regarding the first point: I allow for the $\varepsilon$ to depend on both $f$ and $\sigma_x^2$. Thus I am only requiring it to hold uniformly over all $\sigma^2$ - sorry if this was not clear. With this in mind I believe that all smooth and non-linear $f$ would belong to $\mathcal{C}$. Because, as I believe for any such $f$ and $\sigma_x^2$ we have $f(X)$ is not Gaussian (I am not exactly sure how to prove this, but seems to be folklore), @picky_porpoise's answer gives  a good argument as to why $f \in \mathcal{C}$

Comment: Regarding second point: Thank you! This certainly gives a condition on which $f$'s might be in $\mathcal{C}$, and it holds uniformly over both $\sigma_x^2$ and $\sigma^2$. This is an even stronger requirement, and it might become very useful down the line. Had not thought of using the concept of germs in this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the statement holds without further requirements for $f$. My intuition is that, if there is no lower bound, then we can approximate $f(X)$ via a mean zero Gaussian variable as close as we wish in terms of KL distance. But the KL distance is only zero if $f(X)$ and $Y$ agree, so this seems impossible.

Maybe this can be proved via a contradiction, here is a rough sketch:

1. Assume that there is no lower bound. Then we can find a sequence of mean zero Gaussians $(Y_n)$ such that $KL (f(X) \Vert Y_n) \to 0 $ for $n\to \infty$.
2. The $\sigma_n^2$ of this sequence of Gaussians are w.l.o.g. contained in a finite interval $[a,b]$ since the KL distance will not tend to zero if $\sigma_n^2 \to \infty$ or $\sigma_n^2 \to 0$.
3. Since $(\sigma_n^2)$ is in a compact set we can find a converging subsequence $(\sigma_{n_k}^2)$ such that $\sigma_{n_k}^2 \to \bar\sigma^2$ for $k \to \infty$. Call the mean zero Gaussian for this value $\bar Y$.
4. Since the KL distance is nice enough we can interchange integration and taking limits (dominated convergence should be fine?) to get
   $$
   0 = \lim_{k \to \infty} KL(f(X) \Vert Y_{n_k}) = KL (f(X) \Vert \lim_{k \to \infty} Y_{n_k} ) = KL (f(x) \Vert \bar Y) .
   $$
   But this implies that $f(X) = \bar Y$ in distribution, which is a contradiction, since $f(X)$ cannot be a Gaussian (since $f$ is smooth non-linear.)

*Edit: I assumed from the phrasing of the question that the variance $\sigma_x^2$ of $X$ is a fixed parameter. As pointed out by Abm in the comment below, step 2 does not hold if $\sigma_x^2$ is allowed to vary.*

*Some background on when non-affine transformations of Gaussian variables are again Gaussian can be found [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/392601/gaussian-to-gaussian-transformations) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/200380/normal-distribution-existence-non-affine-invariant-transformation/200407#200407).*

Comment: Thanks for you answer. The problem here is that $f$ being non-linear does not imply that $f(X)$ is non-Gaussian. There was a good post of examples of such non linear transformations that preserve gaussianity, but I cannot seem to find it right now.

Comment: Having thought about it, if we assume that $f(X)$ is non-Gaussian, then your argument should work. Thank you!

Comment: I don't see why (2) should hold.

Comment: Indeed (2) does not hold if we allow for both $\sigma_x^2$ and $\sigma^2$ to vary. Counterexample: any $f$ in the germ of $x$ at $0$, because then if the $\sigma$ and $\sigma_x$ go to zero, the KL divergence tends to 0. But it holds for any fixed $\sigma_x^2$: If $X \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2_x)$ and $f$ is non-linear and smooth with $\mathbb{E}f(X)^2 < \infty$, then $\text{Var}(f(X)) \in (0, \infty)$. Thus we cannot have the $Y$-variances go to 0 nor to $\infty$.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I added some links which discuss the Gaussian transformation stuff and the post now mentions that $\sigma_x^2$ must not vary.