# Uniqueness of change of variable function

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, random-variable, density-function, beta-distribution

Let $X$ and $Y$ be continuous random variables with probability density function as $p_x(X)$ and $p_y(Y)$. If $X$ and $Y$ are related by an invertible function $f$ as $f(X)=Y$, then using change of variable trick, we know that

$p_x(X) = p_y(Y) \left| det( \frac{\partial Y}{\partial X} ) \right| $

where det(.) is a determinant of a matrix.

Question: If $p_x(X)$ and $p_y(Y)$ are fixed, then is $f$ unique?

For example, suppose $X$ is Gaussian random variable with $\mu=0, \sigma=1$ and $Y$ is [beta random variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution) with $\alpha=\beta=2$, then can we say that there exist a unique invertible function $f$ which converts $X$ to $Y$?

Comment: All continuous distributions can be related by invertible functions in uncountably many ways.  See ["probability integral transform"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=probABILITY+integral+transform).  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/200380/normal-distribution-existence-non-affine-invariant-transformation/200407#200407 for illustrations of some of them.