Transformations that preserve normality for all multivariate normal distributions
I am looking for measurable invertible functions $f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ such that for all (non-degenerate) n-dimensional Gaussian random variables $X$, we have that $f(X)$ is still a Gaussian random variable. I conjecture that $f$ has to be affine. Is this true or are additional assumptions on $f$ needed?

If $f$ is affine, measurable and invertible, then it can be represented as $f(X) = AX + b$ for some invertible $n\times n$ matrix $A$ and $n$-dimensional vector $b$. Suppose that $X$ has mean vector $\mu$ and covariance matrix $\Sigma$, then from standard properties of the Gaussian distribution, you get that $f(X)$ is also Gaussian with mean vector $\mu + b$ and covariance matrix $A\Sigma A^{T}$. However, I am not sure whether there are more functions that preserve Gaussianity.

For some intimation of the subtleties that might be involved in showing that the family consists only of affine transformations, see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/200380 for an account of the transformations that preserve a single given Normal distribution.

When you say that $f$ works for every MVN, is $f$ a single function or is it a family of functions?

If $f$ also depends on $\boldsymbol{\mu}$ and $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}$, then there are non-affine transformations that will also work.

@Firebug I think the quantifiers are clear here.  Formally, any measurable $f$ induces a transformation from the space of all distributions on $\mathbb R^n$ to itself.  Calling this $f_,$ it is required that $f$ be invertible and the range of $f_$ when restricted to the set of all continuous MVN distributions, be a subset of the continuous MVN distributions.

@whuber Exactly!

I believe a proof with the characteristic function might work then

Certainly there can be non-linear transformations that preserve normality. However, there has not been plenty of work regarding this to generalize the structure of such transformations. So, to track down all such transformations could be a tough yet interesting one.

Also, would you be interested if you weaken the requirements for linear transformations to work? There are partial converses, FYI.

@User1865345 The key difference here is that normality has to be preserved for any normal random variable the transformation is applied to, not just one specific one. I'm not sure what you mean by weakening the requirements but I would also be interested in partial results, if you have any.

I'm pretty confident the characteristic function will work, but $f$ has to be nice

This is way beyond my level of understanding, but if multivariate analysis is up your alley: S. Nabeya and T. Kariya, “Transformations preserving normality and Wishart-ness,” Journal of Multivariate Analysis, vol. 20, no. 2, pp. 251–264, Dec. 1986, doi: 10.1016/0047-259X(86)90081-3.

I had this in my mind @Firebug. Actually there are many papers especially by Ghosh, Basu and Khatri. One can say this was the culmination.

@Firebug Theorem 2.2 from the paper is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you! Feel free to post it as an answer, I will accept it.

Would @Firebug be bothered if I post the answer as I was writing it  (and yes, I have outlined the proofs in an easier way which, I hope, even you would understand)?

@User1865345 Also sounds good

@Jannis, I erred in thinking that you were talking about a single variable. That's why I mentioned partial converse. But rather you were talking about the family as you mentioned in the comment.

@User1865345 please post an answer, I feel under-qualified in matters of analysis

@Firebug Although the abstract of that paper is difficult to read due to awful formatting, in stating "for fixed" (means) it appears to express some limited version of the present question.  I also believe that the present question has little to do with Normality and everything to do with location-scale families (provided the underlying parent distribution has sufficient support; e.g., the family of a.e. constant distributions won't work).

@whuber I believe Theorem 2.1 shows what kind of function $f$ preserve normality (this is the part that requires fixed means, although I don't claim to understand the proof, but the resulting function $g$ can be easily verified to be the solution), then they show in 2.2 that if $f$ should work across two MVNs, then the 'non-affine part' of the function has to be constant.

I agree with @Firebug; infact the actual result that is answering the question here is the corollary following th 2.2. (which is actually a weak result). Many part has been written hastily and left for the reader to understand. I have tracked through almost but one part is itching me.

The paper, cited by Firebug, answers affirmatively that the functions that preserve multivariate normality are linear  in the sense that, if $\mathcal M:= \{P_{\boldsymbol\theta}\mid \boldsymbol\theta\in\Theta\wedge P_{\boldsymbol\theta}\equiv \mathtt{MultNorm}(\boldsymbol\theta)\}$ where $\Theta:= \{(\boldsymbol\mu,\boldsymbol\Sigma)\in \mathrm{l\!R}^p\times \mathscr P_p\} ,~ \mathscr P_p $ being the collection of all positive definite matrices of order $p,$  and $g:\mathrm{l\!R}^p\to \mathrm{l\!R}^p $ is a bijective bimeasurable transformation  mapping $\mathbf X$ whose law $\mathcal L(\mathbf X)\in \mathcal M$ such that $\mathcal L(g(\mathbf X))\in\mathcal M.$
However, if the question is for which set $A\times B \subseteq \mathrm{l\!R}^p\times \mathscr S_p ,$ one could conclude $g$ is linear that preserves multinormality, the paper does provide a stronger result.
This post would look into the approach taken to prove the result and provide an outline of the same.
WLOG, the following lemmas would be shown for $\boldsymbol\mu=\boldsymbol 0. $
Lemma $1:$ For a fixed $\boldsymbol\Sigma_1, \boldsymbol\Sigma_2\in \mathscr P_p,$ if $\mathbf X\sim \texttt{MutltNorm}(\mathbf 0, \boldsymbol \Sigma_i)$ and $g(\mathbf X)\sim\texttt{MutltNorm}(\boldsymbol\eta_i, \boldsymbol \Psi_i) \in \mathcal M, ~i= \overline{1,2},$ then almost surely $$\mathbf x^\top\left(\boldsymbol \Sigma_1^{-1}-\boldsymbol \Sigma_2^{-1} \right)\mathbf x = (g(\mathbf x) - \boldsymbol\eta_1)^\top\boldsymbol\Psi_1^{-1}(g(\mathbf x) - \boldsymbol\eta_1)- (g(\mathbf x) - \boldsymbol\eta_2)^\top\boldsymbol\Psi_2^{-1}(g(\mathbf x) - \boldsymbol\eta_2) + \ln\vert \boldsymbol\Psi_1\boldsymbol\Sigma_2\vert/\vert \boldsymbol\Sigma_1\boldsymbol\Psi_2\vert.$$
Note $\lambda\circ g\ll \lambda$ and $\lambda(\mathrm d\mathbf y) = \lambda(g(\mathrm d\mathbf x)) $ as $g$ is bijective and bimeasurable; let the corresponding RN derivative be denoted by $k(\mathbf x).$ Therefore $\varphi(\mathbf x; \mathbf 0, \boldsymbol\Sigma_i) =\varphi(g(\mathbf x); \mathbf \eta_i, \boldsymbol\Psi_i )\cdot k(\mathbf x);  $ divide this relation corresponding to $i = 1$ and $2$ to get the result.
$\blacksquare$
Lemma $2:$ If $\mathbf G:=\boldsymbol \Sigma_1^{-1}-\boldsymbol \Sigma_2^{-1} $ and $\mathbf H:= \boldsymbol \Psi_1^{-1}-\boldsymbol \Psi_2^{-1} ,$ then

$\bf G\cong H;$

$\boldsymbol\eta_1 = \boldsymbol\eta_2,$ that is, $\boldsymbol\eta$ is independent of $\boldsymbol\Sigma;$

Almost surely $$\mathbf x^\top\mathbf G\mathbf x = (g(\mathbf x) - \boldsymbol\eta_1)^\top\mathbf H(g(\mathbf x) - \boldsymbol\eta_1).$$


By Lemma $1.,$ it is true almost surely that $\mathbf x^\top\mathbf G\mathbf x =(g(\mathbf x) - \boldsymbol\eta_1)^\top\mathbf H(g(\mathbf x) - \boldsymbol\eta_1) - 2(\boldsymbol\eta_1-\boldsymbol\eta_2)^\top\boldsymbol\Psi_{2}^{-1}(g(\mathbf x) - \boldsymbol\eta_1) + c_2$ where $c_i = (-1)^{i+1}(\boldsymbol\eta_1-\boldsymbol\eta_2)^\top\boldsymbol\Psi_{2}^{-1}(\boldsymbol\eta_1-\boldsymbol\eta_2) +\ln \vert \boldsymbol\Psi_1\boldsymbol\Sigma_2\vert/\vert \boldsymbol\Sigma_1\boldsymbol\Psi_2\vert.$ The right hand side is of the form $\mathbf x^\top \mathbf A\mathbf x +\mathbf a^\top\mathbf X + d,$ where $\bf X$ follows nondegenerate multivariate normal. Equating the mgf of both sides, the latter of which is derived in $[\rm II]$ yields $$\left\vert\mathbf I -2t\boldsymbol{\Sigma}_1^{1/2}\boldsymbol{\mathbf G\Sigma}_1^{1/2}\right\vert^{-1/2}=e^{\chi(t)}\left\vert\mathbf I -2t\boldsymbol{\Psi}_1^{1/2}\boldsymbol{\mathbf H\Psi}_1^{1/2}\right\vert^{-1/2},$$  where $ \chi(t) := 2t^2(\boldsymbol\eta_1-\boldsymbol\eta_2)^\top \boldsymbol\Psi_2^{-1}\left(\boldsymbol\Psi_1^{-1}-2t\mathbf H\right)^{-1}\boldsymbol\Psi_2^{-1}(\boldsymbol\eta_1-\boldsymbol\eta_2) + c_2t. $ For values of $t$ sufficiently close to $t= 0, \mathbf I -2t\boldsymbol{\Sigma}_1^{1/2}\boldsymbol{G\Sigma}_1^{1/2}$ is non-singular and thus in a suitable nbd of $t= 0,$ $$\left\vert\mathbf I -2t\boldsymbol{\Psi}_1^{1/2}\boldsymbol{\mathbf H\Psi}_1^{1/2}\right\vert/\left\vert\mathbf I -2t\boldsymbol{\Sigma}_1^{1/2}\boldsymbol{\mathbf G\Sigma}_1^{1/2}\right\vert=\exp(2(\chi(t)).$$ As explained in this Math.SE post, this leads to $\chi(t)\equiv 0.$ This means  $\left\vert\mathbf I -2t\boldsymbol{\Psi}_1^{1/2}\boldsymbol{\mathbf H\Psi}_1^{1/2}\right\vert= \left\vert\mathbf I -2t\boldsymbol{\Sigma}_1^{1/2}\boldsymbol{\mathbf G\Sigma}_1^{1/2}\right\vert$ for all $t.$ Therefore the eigenvalues of $ \boldsymbol{\Psi}_1^{1/2}\boldsymbol{\mathbf H\Psi}_1^{1/2}$ are equal to that of $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}_1^{1/2}\boldsymbol{\mathbf G\Sigma}_1^{1/2};$ by Sylvester's law of inertia, $\bf G\cong H.$ As $\chi(t)\equiv 0,$ this implies $c_2=\chi^\prime(0) = 0.$ Similarly, $c_1 = 0.$ From $0= c_1- c_2 =(\boldsymbol\eta_1-\boldsymbol\eta_2)^\top\left(\boldsymbol\Psi_{1}^{-1} + \boldsymbol\Psi_{2}^{-1}\right)(\boldsymbol\eta_1-\boldsymbol\eta_2)  $ implies the last two to be proved.
$\blacksquare$
The last implication results this:
Lemma $3:$ For each $\mathbf x\in \mathrm{l\!R}^p,$ there exist unique symmetric matrices $\mathbf B_{ij}$ for $ 1\leq i\leq j\leq p$ such that $$x_ix_j = (g(\mathbf x) - \boldsymbol\eta)^\top\mathbf B_{ij}(g(\mathbf x) - \boldsymbol\eta).$$ Furthermore, $\operatorname{rank}(\mathbf{B}_{ii} )= 1.$
Coming to the main results, first a single $\boldsymbol\mu\in \mathrm{l\!R}^p$ is fixed. What would $g$ that preserves normality for the corresponding distributions look like?
Theorem $1:$ For a fixed $\boldsymbol\mu,$ a preserving bijective bimeasurable transformation $g$ would be of the form almost surely $g(\mathbf x) = h(\mathbf x-\boldsymbol\mu)\mathbf A(\mathbf x-\boldsymbol\mu)+\boldsymbol\eta,$ where $\mathbf A\in\mathsf{GL}(p), \boldsymbol\eta\in \mathrm{l\!R}^p$ and $h:\mathrm{l\!R}^p\to \mathrm{l\!R}$ such that $h(-\mathbf x)= h(\mathbf x)$ and $\operatorname{range}(h)\equiv\{1,-1\} .$
Note first that $\mathbf B_{ji} = \mathbf B_{ij}^\top = \mathbf B_{ij}.$ By lemma $3.,$ there exists a unique $\mathbf b_i\in \mathrm{l\!R}^p $ such that $\mathbf B_{ii} = \mathbf b_i\mathbf b_i^\top$ except for sign change. And $x_i= \pm \mathbf b_i^\top(g(\mathbf x)- \boldsymbol\eta)$ almost surely. $\mathbf B_{1i} = \pm \frac12\left(\mathbf b_1\mathbf b_i^\top +\mathbf b_i\mathbf b_1^\top\right).$ This uniquely determines the signs of $\mathbf b_i$ once the sign of $\mathbf b_1$ is known. Thus with $\mathbf C:= (\mathbf b_1,\ldots, \mathbf b_p)^\top$ being invertible, almost surely $\mathbf x = h(\mathbf x)(g(\mathbf x)-\boldsymbol \eta),$ with $\operatorname{range}{h}\equiv\{+1,-1\}. $ Bijectiveness of $g$ implies $g(\mathbf x)\ne g(-\mathbf x)$ implying $h(\mathbf x)=h(-\mathbf x).$ Thus with $\mathbf A:=\mathbf C^{-1} , ~g(\mathbf x)= h(\mathbf x)\mathbf A\mathbf x+\boldsymbol\eta.$
$\blacksquare$
The next result shows that fixing two distinct $\boldsymbol \mu$s would turn $g$  linear almost surely.
Theorem $2:$ For fixed $\boldsymbol\mu_1, \boldsymbol\mu_2\in \mathrm{l\!R}^p, $ if $g$ is a preserving bijective bimeasurable transformation for the subfamily of $\mathcal M$ determined by $\{(\boldsymbol\mu,\boldsymbol\Sigma)\in \{\boldsymbol\mu_1, \boldsymbol\mu_2\}\times \mathscr P_p\},$  then almost surely  $g(\mathbf x) = \mathbf A\mathbf x+\mathbf a,$ where $\mathbf A\in\mathsf{GL}(p), \mathbf a\in\mathrm{l\!R}^p.$
If Theorem $1.,$ is applied for each $\boldsymbol\mu_i, ~i\in\overline{1,2},$ then there exists $\mathbf A_i\in\mathsf{GL}(p)$ and $\boldsymbol\eta_i\in\mathrm{l\!R}^p$ such that almost surely $g(\mathbf x)=h_i(\mathbf x-\boldsymbol \mu_i)\mathbf  A_i(\mathbf x-\boldsymbol \mu_i)+\boldsymbol\eta_i.$ For $k, l\in\overline{1,2}, $ consider the four disjoint sets $F_{kl}\in\{\mathbf x\in\mathrm{l\!R}^p\mid h_1(\mathbf x-\boldsymbol \mu_1) = (-1)^k, ~h_2(\mathbf x-\boldsymbol \mu_2) = (-1)^l\}.$ Since $\sqcup F_{kl} = \mathrm{l\!R}^p,$ at least one $\lambda(F_{kl})>0. $ Assume that set is $F_{00};$ then almost surely, by definition of the set, $\mathbf  A_1(\mathbf x-\boldsymbol \mu_1)+\boldsymbol\eta_1= \mathbf  A_2(\mathbf x-\boldsymbol \mu_2)+\boldsymbol\eta_2.$
Choose $\mathbf x^{\{s\}}\in F_{00}, ~s\in\overline{0,1, \ldots, p}$ such that they don't lie in a hyperplane. Also, wlog, assume $\mathbf x^{\{s\}}~s\in\overline{1, \ldots, p}$ are linearly independent; so $\mathbf x^{\{0\}} = \sum_{j=1}^pc_j\mathbf x^{\{j\}}$ and since these aren't in a hyperplane, $\sum_j c_j \ne 1.$ For each $s, ~(\mathbf A_1-\mathbf A_2)\mathbf x^{\{s\}} = \mathbf A_1\boldsymbol\mu_1-\mathbf A_2\boldsymbol\mu_2 +\boldsymbol\eta_2-\boldsymbol\eta_1.$ Multiplying $c_s$ to both sides of this relation and summing them up would yield $(\mathbf A_1-\mathbf A_2)\mathbf x^{\{0\}} = \left(\sum_j c_j\right)(\mathbf A_1\boldsymbol\mu_1-\mathbf A_2\boldsymbol\mu_2 +\boldsymbol\eta_2-\boldsymbol\eta_1),$ prompting the sum in the second parenthesis to be $\bf 0,$ which further implies $\mathbf A_1=\mathbf A_2$ owing to $\mathbf x^{\{s\}}, s\in\overline{1,\ldots, p},$ being LIs.
The uniqueness of the other components of $g$ follows from showing that all other $F_{kl}, ~k,l\ne 0$ are of zero measures.
$\blacksquare$
Corollary $1:$ If $g$ preserves $\mathcal M$ for all $\Theta,$ then $g(\mathbf x)= \mathbf A\mathbf x+\mathbf a,$ where $\mathbf A\in\mathsf{GL}(p), \mathbf a\in\mathrm{l\!R}^p.$
--
References:
$\rm[I]$ Transformations preserving normality and Wishart-ness, Seiji Nabeya,  Takeaki Kariya, JOURNAL OF MULTIVARIATE ANALYSIS $20, ~251-264 ~(1986),$ [doi].
$\rm[II] $ Distribution of Quadratic Forms, Marc S Paolella, Wiley Online Library, $2018,$ [doi].

how long did it take to compose this with all the correct LaTeX ... ????

It takes time -- won't deny that. While it took 8 hrs spanned over 2 days, it involved lots of stumbling and thinking. Without that it could be way lesser, as I am pretty fast in my keyboard (normally use phone to write shorter posts, which are in majority). Every once in a while, I do write a longer post like this on sufficient statistic. Main problem was the paper was scant of clear explanations and had poor notations -- had to work that out.
